# 3D scatter color by categorical (x,y) coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am trying to make the scatter dots have the same color if they have the same (x,y) values but with a different Z value.

so far I managed to use one variable either x or y, but I cant "zip" them together somehow.

```
df["X"]=pd.Categorical(df["X"])
df["Y"]=pd.Categorical(df["Y"])
df["X"].cat.codes
df["Y"].cat.codes
bx.scatter(xs,ys,zs, zdir=zs, c=df["X"].cat.codes,cmap="Set1", alpha=1)
```

I tried to zip them individually, I tried making an array out of them...If I try with

```
df["cat"]=pd.Categorical(zip(df["X"],df["Y"]))
df["cat"].cat.codes
```

all I get is one category code, so everything is the same.

Any ideas?
[image]

image for clarification

At first I thought the dates should be the category, but that doesnt makes sense because every day ( since the Zaxes is in datetime format) would have a different a color. 
Insstead, every possible (x,y) pair ie. (1,-1), (2,1) etc should be a category(is it the right word to use?) by itself so then  every  pair should have its own color for example (1,-1) is black, (2,1) is red ***independently*** of its Z coordinate.

Comment: Is the purpose here purely to obtain the plotting result? I guess you have more luck in getting an answer if you provided some example (see [mcve]) of what you are trying to achive. Is this necessarily a 3D plot? are categories somehow related to the coordinates? Is there some necessary order in the categories? Are the categories mutually exclusive or are there overlaps between X and Y? In the latter case are they symmetric, ie. is catX,catY the same as catY,catX?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the plot. hope this helps

Comment: Looking at the plot, it seems to me that the category is simply the date on the z axis. This somehow contradicts the question code. Maybe I'm getting this all wrong, but taken that at least one reader of this question (me) is unable to understand the problem, you might edit it again to make it more clear.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest tried to give a better explanation

Comment: So the sentence below the image is not actually what you want? Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was quite easy in fact, it just took some tinkering round

Original DF has X,Y,Date columns.

```
xs=df.X
ys=df.Y
zs=np.array(df_dates2num)
N=len(df)

val_x=df["X"].tolist()
val_y=df["Y"].tolist()

df["pairs"]=pd.Series(list(zip(val_x,val_y)), index=df.index) #make(x,y) pairs

df["pairs"]=df["pairs"].astype("category") 
df["pairs"]=df.pairs.cat.codes

bx.scatter(xs,ys,zs, zdir=zs, c=df["pairs"], alpha=1, s=50) #scatter dots
```

and it actually works, the only thing missing is to use a more discrete color palette.